# Testng Tests is igored

Tags: testng-dataprovider

```java
  @DataProvider(name = "Standard_ask")
   public Iterator<Object[]> txtReader() throws  IOException{
       File asks = new File("src/test/resources/testdata/standard_ask.txt");
       FileReader reader = new FileReader(asks);
       BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
       String[] c =new String[1000];
       String s = null;
       ArrayList all = new ArrayList();
       while ((s = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)
           all.add(s);
       Iterator ask = all.iterator();
       System.out.println(ask.next());
       return ask;
   }
   // just add test assertion to test why this test is igored
   @Test(dataProvider = "Standard_ask", alwaysRun = true)
   public void testSimilarityFaqTest(Iterator<Object[]> a) throws IOException {
       System.out.println(a.next());
       if (a.hasNext() == true){
           String strResponse = httpClientUtil.doGetForSingleParam(url,a.next());
           JSONObject jsonResponse = JSONObject.parseObject(strResponse);
           Assert.assertEquals(jsonResponse,1);
       }
```

I got below test result

```
 可以教我怎么使用吗

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to 
[Ljava.lang.Object;

at org.testng.internal.Parameters$2.next(Parameters.java:537)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters$2.next(Parameters.java:522)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1165)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Test ignored.

===============================================
Default Suite

## Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

anybody has any testng issus above,or could you please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```java
    @Test(dataProvider = "Standard_ask", alwaysRun = true)
    public void testSimilarityFaqTest(Object a) throws IOException {
    //omitted
```